# Create new branch from master without checking it out

Tags: git, git-checkout

Instead of doing this:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b "master_copy"
```

is there a way to create the `master_copy` branch without either of the above steps?

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
git branch master_copy master
```

[Git branch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)